# Understanding list comprehension on an empty list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am performing list comprehension on an empty list, and I was expecting errors but to my surprise the code ran without any errors.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

block = {'transactions': []}
bs = [OrderedDict([('sender', transaction.sender)])
  for transaction in block['transactions']]
print(bs)
```

The output is `[]`.

Upon inspection in a debugger `transaction` appears to be `<undefined>` during the list comprehension. So why doesn't accessing `transaction.sender` throw an error when `transaction` is undefined?

Comment: There is no error in the code, the `for` loop never iterates so the expression part is never executed. Python doesn't do any type checking.

Comment: None of this is specific to list comprehensions.

Comment: The debugger is being misleading; it sees the name in the code, but the name simply does not exist until the iterator for `block['transactions']` yields a value, which it never does.

Comment: @chepner, yeah, that explains it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked "Why doesn't then treating `transaction` as an object and accessing its non existent `attribute` throws error when `transaction` clearly isn't an object ?"

The answer is that the attribute is never accessed. Since `block['transactions']` is an empty list, and the comprehension runs on the loop `for transaction in block['transactions']`, the loop is never executed, the object is never examined, and the attribute is never accessed. Thus the variable `bs` ends up being an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the equivalent expansion of your list comprehension using a for loop.

```
bs = []
for transaction in block['transactions']:
    bs.append(OrderedDict([('sender', transaction.sender)]))
print(bs)
```

The output will still be `[]` because the body of the for loop is never executed.

So Python will not crash on your list comprehension because it never tries to access the `sender` attribute of `transaction`.